# BATCH, summarize variables inside FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a batch file with a FOR loop inside like this:

```
set /a target=5

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%target%) DO (
    echo %%G)
```

It works like a charm %%G will 1,2,3,4,5.

Now I want a new wariable like test=%%G+1 and it will be: 2,3,4,5,6

But with this code it didn't works.

```
set /a target=5

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%target%) DO (
    echo %%G
    set /a test=%%G+1
    echo %test%
)
```

test variable will be every time: 6

What should I do?

Thanks
Roberto

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `EnabledDelayedExpansion` when evaluating variables which are set inside a `FOR` loop:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a target=5

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%target%) DO (
    echo %%G
    set /a test=%%G+1

    REM Note the exclamation marks.
    REM This is delayed expansion notation.
    echo !test!
)

ENDLOCAL
```

If you do not use delayed expansion, then all variables are evaluated on the first pass of the `FOR` loop, so `%test%` will not actually have a value at this time.
By turning on delayed expansion (and using the `!test!` notation), the script will evaluate the value of `!test!` *on each pass*.